# How to repeat the question after the user chose the wrong answer on my quiz program in java

Tags: java

I want to make a quiz program in java, i need an output that if the user chose the wrong answer all question will repeat until the the user chose the correct answer and put an output that must display also the key to correction and i hope you all help guys on my quiz program in java. and i want to correct my score when 5 wrong answer will back in the question with two wrong answer. when i run the code the score is 178 points with the 5 wrong answer in code but when i perfect the quiz the score is 150 that's is the total score of my quiz

````
  int score = 0;
           int count = 0;

        String name;
        String age;
        String subject;
        String course;
        String schoolyear;
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
        age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age");
        subject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your subject");
        course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your course");
        schoolyear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your school year today");



        boolean a = true;
        boolean b = true;
        boolean c = true;

 do {
        if (a == true) {
        String question1 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What year when the release of Java?\n"
                         + ("2 points \n")
                         + ("The answer is B\n")
                         + "(A.)1990\n (B.)1991\n (C.)1998\n (D.)1980\n" );



    if("B".equals(question1)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Correct\n");
        score+= 2;
                count++;
                a = false;

    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect\n");

    }

 }       

        if (b == true) {
        String question2 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Who created Java?\n"
                         + ("2 points \n")
                         + ("The answer is B\n")
                         + "(A.)Manny Pacquio\n (B.)James Gosling\n (C.)James Bond\n (D.)Matt Damon\n");

    if("B".equals(question2)) 

    {
            System.out.println("Correct\n");
        score+= 2;
                count++;
                b = false;


    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect\n");

    } 

    }  

        if (c == true) {
        String question3 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("In Which team where Java created?\n"
                         + ("2 points \n")
                         + ("The answer is D\n")
                         + "(A.)Team Black\n (B.)Team White\n (C.)Team Brown\n (D.)Team Green\n" );


    if("D".equals(question3))
    {
        System.out.println("Correct\n");
        score+= 2;
                count++;
                c = false;


    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
    }
} while (count <3);     

   } 


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Your score: " + score);
       System.out.println(100 *score/150 + "%");


       if (score >=150) {
       System.out.println("Excellent");
       } else if (score >=140) {
       System.out.println("Ultimatum!");
       } else if (score >=120) {
       System.out.println("Great Job!");
       } else if (score >=100) {
       System.out.println("Good Job!");
       } else if (score >=80) {
       System.out.println("Pass");
       } else if (score >=60) {
       System.out.println("Passangawa");
       } else if (score >=40) {
       System.out.println("Satisfy");
       } else if (score >=20) {
       System.out.println("Try again");
       } else if (score >=0) {
       System.out.println("Failed");    
       } else {
       System.out.println("Wasted!");  



```All question will repeat until the user chose the correct answer and i need the score will be correct when one or more wrong answer will back to answer again and the score will back to its correct score with the 28 question in total.
````

Comment: And what if i have many question on my quiz?

Comment: Many question like ? You can repeat all questions in a loop !

Comment: Did you get your answer from the answers posted below or I should help you ?

Comment: yeah i need another opinion

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use while loop and add some flag if the answer is correct and iterate until it will be correct

**QUESTION**

```
public class Question {
private String question;
private String answer;

public Question(String question, String answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
```

}

**MAIN**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0;
        Question q1 = new Question("What year when the release of Java?\n" + ("2 points \n")
                + "(A.)1990\n (B.)1991\n (C.)1998\n (D.)1980\n", "B");
        Question q2 = new Question("What is hourse" + ("2 points \n") + "(A.)Animal\n (B.)Dog\n (C.)Human\n (D.)Lake\n",
                "A");

        List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        questionsList.add(q1);
        questionsList.add(q2);

        for(Question question : questionsList) {
            boolean isCorrectQuestion = false;
            while (!isCorrectQuestion) {
                String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question.getQuestion());
                if (question.getAnswer().equals(answer)) {
                    System.out.println("Correct\n");
                    score += 2;
                    isCorrectQuestion = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect\n");

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

By the way first release of Java was in 1996

Comment: What if i have multiple questions in my quiz program? @Rafal

Comment: @VinceJackLudovice Then I suggest to create class Question when you will store Question, Answer and number of question and make some list of this question put this while loop inside for each when you iterate through your list of questions

Comment: can you give me a example? @Rafal

Comment: @VinceJackLudovice Just made an edit to my answer. Check it please

Comment: no, i don.t get it, your satying thta i create another class for class question, answer  and number of of question and make some list of this question?

Comment: One class for all of this. Number actually is not neccessary. So you can create object where you store your question and answer for that question right? And then you create list of few questions

Comment: and i repeat it in all 26 question on my quiz?

Comment: You have to somehow create those questions. You can also put them into file and read them

Comment: @VinceJackLudovice I don't understand your question

Comment: Did you see my code? You have class question where you define how you question looks like. You dont create that if statements for all your questions. And that for loop makes all your job. You just put there question and that's all. In Question class you can also define number of score for question. All you have to do is create e.g 26 objects with questions and add them to your questionList and that's all

Comment: but i can't post my code in the comment because it's  so long to post it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int score = 0;
        int count = 0;

        boolean a = true;
        boolean b = true;

        do {
            if (a == true) {
                String question1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What year when the release of Java?\n"
                        + ("2 points \n")
                        + "(A.)1990\n (B.)1991\n (C.)1998\n (D.)1980\n");


                if ("B".equals(question1)) {
                    System.out.println("Correct\n");
                    score += 2;
                    count++;
                    a = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
                }

            }


            if (b == true) {
                String question2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("#2: What year when the release of Java?\n"
                        + ("2 points \n")
                        + "(A.)1990\n (B.)1991\n (C.)1998\n (D.)1980\n");


                if ("B".equals(question2)) {
                    System.out.println("Correct\n");
                    score += 2;
                    count++;
                    b = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
                }

            }

        } while (count < 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have multiple question in my quiz program? @Tasha

Comment: Create individual boolean variables for each question in conjunction with an if-statement enclosing the question, like: if(isWrong) { // question }, also create a counter variable to count the correct answered questions, which should then be used in the while loop, as to terminate once all questions have been answered correctly.

Comment: can you give me a example on how to make it?

Comment: Edited code in the answer. The boolean values "a" and "b" determine if a question should be asked again in the next iteration of the do-while-loop. The condition in the while part determines if all questions have already been answered correctly. Count ceiling equals amount of questions, obviously.

Comment: What if i have an 28 questions in my quiz?

Comment: Then you should consider the solution from Rafal Sokalski.

Comment: or i just put boolean c for another question?

Comment: Yes, you will have to duplicate and create for every question a variable of type boolean with a unique name.

Comment: i try the boolean a - z in the code but  when i run the the code, if you 5 wrong answer it will back to the last question with wrong answer, but may problem is the scoring  because the total score only 150 points in all but with 5 wrong answer it will total on 178 points in total